# travel time from google maps API does not vary with time of day

Tags: r, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api, travel-time

I used `gmapdistance` to calculate travel time between two points in New York at different times. Can someone please tell me why is the travel time same and is not varying with time of day?

```
library(gmapsdistance)
library(lubridate)

# key is set

temp1 = gmapsdistance(
  origin = "40.75905289665592+-73.97693625311344",
  destination = "40.76264792279165+-73.99683999171252",
  mode = "driving",
  key = key,
  departure = as.numeric(ymd_hms("2021-09-11 15:00:00"))
)
temp1$Time


temp2 = gmapsdistance(
  origin = "40.75905289665592+-73.97693625311344",
  destination = "40.76264792279165+-73.99683999171252",
  mode = "driving",
  key = key,
  departure = as.numeric(ymd_hms("2021-09-11 19:00:00"))
)
temp2$Time

temp3 = gmapsdistance(
  origin = "40.75905289665592+-73.97693625311344",
  destination = "40.76264792279165+-73.99683999171252",
  mode = "driving",
  key = key,
  departure = as.numeric(ymd_hms("2021-09-11 23:00:00"))
)
temp3$Time
```

Comment: Distance is only 1.3 miles so I wouldn't expect the duration to vary too much. That said, trying your coords on my side, I get slightly different results.

Comment: ^^ at different times of the day.

Comment: I started getting different travel times once I added another argument - `traffic_model`

Comment: The rdocumentation suggested that `departure` is the time and distance can be computed at the desired time of departure. The option departure is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UCT.